# How do I install Python 3 on an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install python 3.x on an AWS EC2 instance and:

```
sudo yum install python3
```

doesn't work:

```
No package python3 available.
```

I've googled around and I can't find anyone else who has this problem so I'm asking here. Do I have to manually download and install it?

Comment: Possibly yes, it may not yet be available for Amazon Linux (or clarify if you're using a different OS).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing python3 on RHEL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087184/installing-python3-on-rhel)

Comment: Hi, yes it's the 'standard' Amazon Linux OS. Happy to manually install but there are a few things missing ( and I thought it best to check before spending time messing about :)

Comment: @BMW the answer you linked to was helpful but not enough to get it working on its own.

Comment: Since the AMI underneath changes often, it may be useful to check the release notes for the most recent machine, available here: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/#Release_Notes

Comment: Now i can run on Amazon Linux 2 AMI. sudo yum install python3.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

If you do a

```
sudo yum list | grep python3
```

you will see that while they don't have a "python3" package, they do have a "python34" package, or a more recent release, such as "python36". Installing it is as easy as:

```
sudo yum install python34 python34-pip
```

Comment: This seems to be the simpler answer. Did AWS update their packages between when @Jake_Howard posted an answer and you did?

Comment: I haven't verified that this is true, but I'll reward the best answer on trust. I'm not sure if they have upgraded since I answered, there are certainly a fair few blog posts out there outlining how to do it the old fashioned way. The even better approach that I found was just to use Ubuntu instead! :)

Comment: I think this method is best.  The approach @Jake_Howard outlined worked for me in an arbitrary CentOS VM.  However, I believe that answer still needs some editing in terms of what's performed as root.

Comment: To use pip3 add the following symbolic link # ln -s /usr/bin/pip-3.4 /usr/bin/pip3

Comment: `sudo yum install python34` doesn't work for me. It says `No package python34 available.`

Comment: @SohanShirodkar you may have been unlucky and just caught a new release -- their September release moved to `python35` ... here's where you can see the newest releases: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/#Release_Notes

Comment: Use @Jake_Howard 's answer, if you do not have access on your aws YUM manager to python 3.

Comment: In 2018, `sudo yum install python36` is also available. also don't forget to install latest pip: `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip` and then you can `python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv` for a virtual env. ref: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/

Comment: This answer, although acceptable, wasted my time uninstalling python 3.4 to install 3.6, since the version of python3 will not always be python34, as assumed by the answer. In fact, python 3.4 is being deprecated March 2019 by Django, being replaced by 3.6.

Comment: I can run 'sudo yum install python3 python3-pip' today.

Comment: `sudo yum install python36 python36-pip` worked for me, thanks !!

Answer (score 86):

> Note: This may be obsolete for current versions of Amazon Linux 2 since late 2018 (see comments), you can now directly install it via `yum install python3`.

In Amazon Linux **2**, there isn't a `python3[4-6]` in the default yum repos, instead there's the [Amazon Extras Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library).

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install python3
```

If you want to set up isolated virtual environments with it; using `yum install`'d `virtualenv` tools don't seem to reliably work.

```
virtualenv --python=python3 my_venv
```

Calling the venv module/tool is less finicky, and you could double check it's what you want/expect with `python3 --version` beforehand.

```
python3 -m venv my_venv
```

---

Other things it can install (versions as of 18 Jan 18):

```
[ec2-user@x ~]$ amazon-linux-extras list
  0  ansible2   disabled  [ =2.4.2 ]
  1  emacs   disabled  [ =25.3 ]
  2  memcached1.5   disabled  [ =1.5.1 ]
  3  nginx1.12   disabled  [ =1.12.2 ]
  4  postgresql9.6   disabled  [ =9.6.6 ]
  5  python3=latest  enabled  [ =3.6.2 ]
  6  redis4.0   disabled  [ =4.0.5 ]
  7  R3.4   disabled  [ =3.4.3 ]
  8  rust1   disabled  [ =1.22.1 ]
  9  vim   disabled  [ =8.0 ]
 10  golang1.9   disabled  [ =1.9.2 ]
 11  ruby2.4   disabled  [ =2.4.2 ]
 12  nano   disabled  [ =2.9.1 ]
 13  php7.2   disabled  [ =7.2.0 ]
 14  lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2   disabled  [ =10.2.10_7.2.0 ]
```

Comment: "Topic python3 has end-of-support date of 2018-08-22" this is not supported anymore

Comment: @zenbeni did the default system Python get bumped to Python 3?

Comment: @NickT python3-3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 is actually installed through 'yum install python3' you don't use amazon linux extras anymore for python

Comment: I'm mildly confused why this keeps getting upvotes (4 in the last month) if it's now obsolete.

Answer (score 48):

Here are the steps I used to manually ***compile and install*** python3 for anyone else who wants to do it as it's not super straight forward. ***EDIT:*** It's almost certainly easier to use the yum package manager (see other answers).

Note, you'll probably want to do **`sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`** before doing this otherwise pip won't install.

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.2/Python-3.4.2.tgz
tar zxvf Python-3.4.2.tgz
cd Python-3.4.2
sudo yum install gcc
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3
make
sudo yum install openssl-devel
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /opt/python3/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3
python3 (should start the interpreter if it's worked (quit() to exit)
```

Comment: To use `pip3` also link it with `sudo ln -s /opt/python3/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip3`.

Comment: @xpmatteo - which bit is wrong? Is it just a step or the approach that you object to?

Comment: @Jake_Howard It is not true that the only way is to manually install Python3. That is certainly an option, but you can also do `yum install python35` as others have mentioned. If you would kindly amend your answer I will remove my downvote :)

Comment: @xpmatteo - re-worded the answer to remove the incorrect phrase. For posterity: at the time of asking the question and posting the original answer, I wasn't aware of the ability to use yum with a specific version of python3 (see other answers), or these packages weren't available at the time of original writing.

Comment: Worked for me! This days you can use 3.7.2 instead of 3.4.2

Comment: This is a very good answer, since you can use the same approach to install any version you want. The package manager does not include all.

Comment: I just built `3.9.16` from source because the `yum` repos only support 3.7.16 currently. Thanks @Jake_Howard, your approach worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

EC2 (on the Amazon Linux AMI) currently supports python3.4 and python3.5.

```
sudo yum install python35
sudo yum install python35-pip
```

Comment: Props for this answer! Python3 is not `python3` on AWS instances by default. Very frustrating to swap between Ubuntu and AWS Linux when working!

Comment: This works and you can confirm if 3.5 is the latest you have with this command `sudo yum list | grep python3` and to once you've installed confirm by typing `pythono3 --version`  - yes python3 as python will return v2.

Comment: sudo amazon-linux-extras install python3.8

Answer (score 21):

As of Amazon Linux version 2017.09 python 3.6 is now available:

```
sudo yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip
```

See the [Release Notes](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.09-release-notes/) for more info and other packages

Comment: pip3 is not linked, so if you want to use it, sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip-3.6 /usr/bin/pip3

Comment: `-s /usr/bin/pip-3.6 /usr/bin/pip3` failed for me so I ended up using `pip-3.6 install xyz`

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Linux now supports python36.

python36-pip is not available. So need to follow a different route.

```
sudo yum install python36 python36-devel python36-libs python36-tools

# If you like to have pip3.6:
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: This is the easiest way that works in 2020 of all the others.

Comment: This does not work on Amazon Linux 2 - `python36` and all other related packages are held in `amazon-linux-extras` now and don't install the expected packages which others may have as dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

As  @NickT said,  there's no python3[4-6] in the default yum repos in Amazon Linux *2*, as of today it uses 3.7 and looking at all answers here we can say it will be changed over time.

I was looking for python3.6 on Amazon Linux 2 but `amazon-linux-extras` shows a lot of options but no python at all. in fact, you can try to find the version you know in `epel` repo:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel

yum search python | grep "^python3..x8"

python34.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000
python36.x86_64 : Interpreter of the Python programming language
```

Comment: Unfortunately the only version it shows anymore now is python34.x86_64, they must've removed python36.x86_64 which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Check the packages available

A> amazon-linux-extras

Find the required python package with version from the list

B> sodo amazon-linux-extras enable python<version_available>

C> sudo yum clean metadata && sudo yum install python<version_available>

Answer (score 1):

Adding to all the answers already available for this question, I would like to add the steps I followed to install Python3 on AWS EC2 instance running CentOS 7. You can find the entire details at this link.

https://aws-labs.com/install-python-3-centos-7-2/

First, we need to enable SCL. SCL is a community project that allows you to build, install, and use multiple versions of software on the same system, without affecting system default packages.

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
```

Now that we have SCL repository, we can install the python3

```
sudo yum install rh-python36
```

To access Python 3.6 you need to launch a new shell instance using the Software Collection scl tool:

```
scl enable rh-python36 bash
```

If you check the Python version now you’ll notice that Python 3.6 is the default version

```
python --version
```

It is important to point out that Python 3.6 is the default Python version only in this shell session. If you exit the session or open a new session from another terminal Python 2.7 will be the default Python version.

Now, Install the python development tools by typing:

```
sudo yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’
```

Now create a virtual environment so that the default python packages don't get messed up.

```
mkdir ~/my_new_project
cd ~/my_new_project
python -m venv my_project_venv
```

To use this virtual environment,

```
source my_project_venv/bin/activate
```

Now, you have your virtual environment set up with python3.

Answer (score 0):

try this

sudo yum install python34 python34-pip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Here is the one command to install python3 on Amazon linux ec2 instance:

## $sudo yum install python3 -y

## $python3 --version

Python 3.7.6

Answer (score -4):

On Debian derivatives such as Ubuntu, use apt. Check the apt repository for the versions of Python available to you. Then, run a command similar to the following, substituting the correct package name:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

On Red Hat and derivatives, use yum. Check the yum repository for the versions of Python available to you. Then, run a command similar to the following, substituting the correct package name:

```
sudo yum install python36
```

On SUSE and derivatives, use zypper. Check the repository for the versions of Python available to you. Then. run a command similar to the following, substituting the correct package name:

```
sudo zypper install python3
```