# Getting pip to work on a python 3 install on RedHat 7.2 on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, redhat

I followed this guide to install Python 3.4.2 on a RedHat 7.2 instance on an EC2 server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27676035/5201726

I read that python 3.4 ships with pip installed, but I cant seem to get it to run, I've tried:

```
pip3

python3 pip
```

Any ideas? I followed the guide to the letter. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It returns this:
    [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx Python-3.4.2]$ pip3 --version
    -bash: pip3: command not found

Comment: `python3 --version`?

Comment: It returns this: 
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx Python-3.4.2]$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2

Comment: Try this: `yum install -y python-setuptools --disablerepo=chl`

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx Python-3.4.2]$ sudo yum install -y python-setuptools --disablerepo=chl
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos


Error getting repository data for chl, repository not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access to `pip` command the default Python 3.4 installation you can [create a Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/#optionally-create-a-virtual-environment) which is the preferred way to install non-distribution packages.

```
  python3.4 -m venv myvenv
  source myvenv/bin/activate
  pip install Pyramid  # Install Pyramid package
```

Comment: When virtual environment is created it is locked to a certain Python version. If you use python3.4 to create virtual environment it is for this version and pip will work with it.