# Unable to import BeautifulSoup from bs4 on AWS Cloud9

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, cloud9-ide

So I've tried to follow the answer here but have no luck: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=822214&tstart=0

Only line in my python file is `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` which returns `ImportError: No module named bs4`.

I've created my virtualenv and have activated it, terminal shows `(vpy36)` at the beginning of each line.

`python --version` returns Python 3.6.2

`python -m pip install bs4` returns `Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.0.1)`

`Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from bs4) (4.6.0)`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does `pip --version` return ?

Comment: `pip 10.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Comment: I am not sure but why is pip not in the vpy36/ folder and in the vpy36/local/ folder ? I might be wrong here.

Comment: @BcK I don't know? I think it is how AWS Cloud 9 is set up? If I deactivate virtualenv and do `pip --version` I get `pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: @VincentNguyen try installing pip3 with: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: @Jatimir AWS Cloud9 doesn't use apt-get it uses yum. I tried installing pip3 with yum, it just defaults to pip in my virtualenv

Comment: @VincentNguyen Oh yeah, I missed that. What's the output of `pip3 --version`? Have you installed python 3.6 through `yum install python36` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544610/4796844)?

Comment: `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)`

But when I do `python3 -m pip3 install bs4` I get `No module named pip3`

Comment: @VincentNguyen I assumed you already tried that, but maybe you haven't. Just try to activate `virtualenv` and `pip install bs4`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my .py file into `/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`

Comment: @Jatimir Agreed

Comment: If you are in a position, reinstall all python versions from scratch. This is just a temporary solution.