# How to install Python 3 on AWS Linux RHEL Free Tier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

When I try to install, it says that 2.7 is already installed. I want Python 3. How to install that?

[image]

I tried using `python3`, cannot find package:
[image]

Comment: See [How do I install Python3 on an AWS EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669927/how-do-i-install-python3-on-an-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 is a different package:

```
sudo yum install python3
```

Comment: it looks like you need a subversion as well... Try `sudo yum install python36`

Answer (score 0):

Check your RHEL release version using

```
$lsb_release -a
```

Then depending on your OS version follow answers in [Installing Python 3 on RHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087184/installing-python-3-on-rhel) for installation

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one command to install python3 on Amazon linux 2:

## $sudo yum install python3 -y

## $python3 --version

Python 3.7.6