# SL CLI Broken after upgrading to 5.1.0

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Recently upgraded to SoftLayer API version 5.1.0 from version 4.*. Now when I try to utilize it, I get the below error output. I'm assuming this has to do with python version being used but being pretty new to Python and reading how messing with the version of Python in RHEL is Dangerous I have been hesitant to make changes.

```
$ slcli
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/slcli", line 7, in <module>
    from SoftLayer.CLI.core import main
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SoftLayer/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from SoftLayer.API import * # NOQA
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 11, in <module>
    from SoftLayer import config
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SoftLayer/config.py", line 11, in <module>
    from SoftLayer import utils
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SoftLayer/utils.py", line 63
    for key, val in self.items()}
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Machine information-

- RHEL 6.7
- pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the system requirements for the Soflayer Python API client it works with Python 2.7,  3.3 or higher. I recomed you to upgrade your Python to 2.7.9 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this issue, I follow these instructions to get python 34 installed side by side w the 2.6 version and the sl cli works now

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250834/6348212