# How to install python 3 on a ssh hadoop system (sandbox) without pip and brew?

Tags: python, hadoop, ssh

Any possible command on terminal of ssh hadoop environment to install and run python without using pip or brew? Also, I have already tried

```
yum install python
```

that gives me Python version 2.6 that creates more trouble.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087184/problems-installing-python3-on-rhel

Answer (score 1):

You will not find a python3 installation via yum. You should simply use the standard python.org installation:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.5/Python-3.4.5.tgz
tar xfz Python-3.4.5.tgz 
cd Python-3.4.5/
./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Go to [python.org](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/) to choose your desired Python version to install.