# Installed python3, getting command not found error in terminal on RHEL

Tags: python, python-3.x, rhel7

I installed python3, when I enter python3 in the terminal (on RHEL) I get an error saying 'command not found'. Entering python gets me the 2.x version that came on the computer. Any advice on how I can access python3 from the terminal?

Comment: it seems you need to add python3 to your path variable.

Please refer to this discussion: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-does-the-default-path-get-set-on-rhel-584001/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Python 3 on RHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087184/installing-python-3-on-rhel)

Answer (score 2):

Where did you install Python 3 from?   Out of the box on RHEL 6 and 7 there are no Python 3 packages. There are supported packages from Red Hat that are part of Red Hat Software collections.  To use them you have to enable the RHSCL repo, then install rh-python36. These packages are installed in `/opt/rh`, not `/usr/bin`, so you need to use `scl enable rh-python36 bash` to get a shell with the correct path.

See [How to install Python 3 on RHEL](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/) on the Red Hat Developer Blog.

It covers:

- Installing Python 3, venv, virtualenv, pipenv
- Tips for working with Red Hat Software Collections
- How to use Python virtual environments so you can safely do pip installs that are isolated and reproducible