# ImportError while installing python 3.6.x on a linux machine

Tags: python-3.x, linux, rhel

I'm trying to install Python 3.6.9, I followed these steps:
-wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz

-tar xzf Python-3.6.3.tar.xz

-cd into the python directory

-python setup.py install

I get this error:
[image: Error I get is]

I tried with another version:

-wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tar.xz

-tar xJf Python-3.6.3.tar.xz

but i get the same error

Please Help
Note: I have no root access on this computer nor internet connection( I have to download it using another computer)

Comment: looks like you're trying to build python from source? - maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087184/installing-python-3-on-rhel) is helpful?

Comment: @MrFuppes but I don't have root access

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, then Python 3 is already there via [software collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-python) where you have to enable the channel/repo. If [RHEL 8](https://developers.redhat.com/rhel8/#assembly-field-sections-9585) it's a bit more straightforward.

Comment: it's a RHEL 4, it has Python 2.3 installed